# Join on comma separated values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, join

I have a MySQL Table like this

Table 1

```
1    [1803,1605]
2    [1605]
3    [1405,989]
```

Table 2

```
1803 List_item_1
1605 item_2
1405 item_3
```

and so on

I should get an output like

```
1  List_item_1,item_2
2  item_2
```

so on

Please Help me with this

Comment: So basically you want to replace CSV of ids for a CSV of names?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I have to get the names of those values (values in comma separated row) for example if I have 1,2,3 I have to get result like a,b,c (these are the names assigned to those id'd)

Comment: @Ezenhis exactly

Comment: So where is the third row in the result? What are the table names and column names?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel table1(id,categories).......table2(categoryid,name)

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I am new to this site...Please let me know if u not understood my question

Comment: Does your version of MySQL support the JSON functions? And is the column containing these values defined as a json column `[1803,1605]` ??

Comment: @RiggsFolly my version supports json...but the datatype for values is varchar

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLServer? Please dont spam tags

Comment: @RiggsFolly mysql

Comment: See this is why jointables using comma delimited keys is such a bad idea

Comment: @RiggsFolly any idea about how to join them....

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets and use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.id, TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM t1.csv))) > 0
GROUP BY t1.id
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=644409993bcd0dfc82eb1a3de78d5fda)

Answer (score 0):

I use a simplified matching here on category id that depends them being roughly the same length

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON  a.categories LIKE CONCAT('%',b.categoryId, '%')
GROUP BY id
```

and here is one variant using REGEXP_LIKE that should be a bit more flexible

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON  REGEXP_LIKE(a.categories, CONCAT('[\\[,]+', b.categoryId, '[\\],]+'))
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.7 and newer versions you can use `JSON_CONTAINS()` in the ON clause:

```
select t1.id, group_concat(t2.name) as names
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on json_contains(t1.categories, cast(t2.categoryid as json))
group by t1.id
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/odnDBDagYSdJvcK1P2TCMd/0

But you should consider to store your data in a normalized schema. Since it seems to be a *many-to-many* relation, you would need a third table like

```
items_cats: 
------------------
item_id     cat_id
------------------
      1       1803
      1       1605
      2       1605
      3       1405
```

Then your query would be:

```
select ic.item_id, group_concat(t2.name) as names
from items_cats ic
join table2 t2 on t2.categoryid = ic.cat_id
group by ic.item_id
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/izHPHaV5iLsNvVnAfZs3Jo/0

This method can utilize an index for the JOIN, and improves the performance significantly, when your data size grows.